# Touch detection gets worse after some level reloads

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2D game with unity I found a problem on Android. I have a ball that jumps every times I touch the screen, in the Editor it works perfectly but on Android after some times I "reload" (load again the level) the ball seems to not recognize close touch and the game become unplayable. When I close the game ( deleting it from the recent apps ) and reopen it, it works perfectly again. I have about 30 gameobjects in the scene for all the time but the point is why this problem is more evident after some reload? When I reload the level shouldn't it be resetted?

I detect the touch and get the ball jumps with:

```
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0) || Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().constraints &= ~RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionY;
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().constraints = RigidbodyConstraints2D.FreezePositionX;
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity=Vector.up*speed;
        gameObject.GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
        gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().isKinematic=false;

    }
```

This code is in Update() , in the main script of the game, where I've many things in the Update() but the most are carried out when the player lose.
The script is attached to a gameobject that also has 
-sprite renderer
-rigidbody2d
-polygoncollider2D
-audiosource

Comment: please post your code for touch description and information on the script it is in, and what kind of object it is attached

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Smells like some memory leak to me.
Without source code examples it is just guessing, but I would check for event subscriptions (EventX += HandlerY). Maybe it is possible to register some events multiple times with no mechanism that cleans up unused subscriptions.

See also [Find memory leaks in Unity](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/791464/toolstechniques-to-find-memory-leak-roots-in-unity.html)

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to Unity and I don't  understand very well what are you saying

Comment: What I try to say is:
I suppose that each reload does something, which should be done only once.
So, on the next reload it should not be done again, or you first need to "reset" something.

Comment: I've checked in the Start() and I noticed that every time the scene start I request my banner, maybe is this the problem?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, depends on what you do with it and how... You really should add your code to the question, without it`s hard to help.